# Not able to concatenate Values Based on Different columns in case when statement -Snowflake

Tags: case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hope are you doing well!..I am trying to concatenate values of case when statement based on different columns in snowflake ..Please find the block of code below

```
select *,

case when checkouttime is null then ',Patient is not checked out' else '' END
+ case when primarypatientinsuranceid is null then ',No insurance information' else '' END
+ case when closedby is null then ',Encounter not signed off' else '' END
+ case when billingtabcheckeddate is null then ',Billing tab is not checked' else '' 
+ case when alreadyrouted is null then ',Missing slip already routed' else 'Valid Missing slip'

END as resultant

from final
```

I am getting the error saying  " Unexpected as"

I am trying to build the resultant column output as the following

```
Patient is not checked out/Billing tab is not checked
Missing slip already routed
Encounter not signed off/No insurance information /Billing tab is not checked
Valid Missing slip
```

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner alternative that adds commas as necessary, using `array_to_string(array_construct_compact())`:

```sql
with data as (
    select null checkouttime
        , 2 primarypatientinsuranceid
        , null closedby
        , 4 billingtabcheckeddate
        , 5 alreadyrouted
)

select array_to_string(array_construct_compact(
    iff(checkouttime is null, 'Patient is not checked out', null) 
    , iff(primarypatientinsuranceid is null, 'No insurance information', null)
    , iff(closedby is null, 'Encounter not signed off', null)
    , iff(billingtabcheckeddate is null, 'Billing tab is not checked', null)
    , iff(alreadyrouted is null, 'Missing slip already routed', 'Valid Missing slip')
    ), ',  ')
as resultant
from data
```

Comment: Thanks @Felipe...This really helps!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's the answer you wanted :)

Comment: Thanks @Felipe!...Yes I have accepted the answer...

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake, you use "||" to concat strings, not "+":

```
select 
case when true then ',Patient is not checked out' else '' END
|| case when false then ',No insurance information' else '' END
|| case when true then ',Encounter not signed off' else '' END
|| case when true then ',Billing tab is not checked' else '' END
|| case when false then ',Missing slip already routed' else 'Valid Missing slip' END 
as resultant;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html

Comment: Thanks @ Eric Lin..This is really helpful....Can you please let me know how to remove the first character coming as comma

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify? I don't fully understand your above question.

Comment: Hi Eric....In the output for resultant I get a comma in the beginning ...I was asking as to how to get rid of the comma...

Comment: That's because there was a "," in ',Patient is not checked out' I guess?